# Retrieve literal value of HTML elements in javascript, without encoding ampersands

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I'm trying to retrieve the literal contents of some HTML elements, **without encoding ampersands**. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

An example : 
If I set the URL :

```
http://www.google.com?q=foo&bla=bar&amp;kitties=yay
```

on an anchor tag, and try to retrieve it again with innerHTML, or by using XMLSerializer.serializeToString() the URL (as href) comes back as :

```
http://www.google.com?q=foo&amp;bla=bar&amp;kitties=yay
```

(the first non-encoded ampersand has been encoded, and the encoded ampersand is unchanged[still encoded, not double encoded])

I'm aware that this encoded version the browser gives me back is correct(ed) HTML and wouldn't normally cause problems, but I have people looking at these URLs who do not understand that &amp; is &, and who will copy and paste the URL to verify it. I also don't think its safe to decode the URL as often these URLs have encoded urls on the end, which should remain encoded, and they don't seem to get double-encoded. I suppose this is also incorrect as the URL is corrected and not "encoded" as such. I also need the HTML tag part (e.g. the `<a>`), so can't just get the nodeValue/innerText/textContent/data .

Any suggestions greatfully received - I'd include a jsfiddle but even that encodes stuff so its not helpful! Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm stuck!

Comment: Mark the URIs as code to stop Stackoverflow treating them as raw HTML. (I'd fix it up myself, but I'm not certain what the original value was)

Comment: Can you include the HTML for a link that's giving you problems? Also including the Javascript that doesn't work may help.

Comment: @Anthony - something like : var testAnchor = document.createElement('a');
testAnchor.href = "http://www.google.com?q=foo&bla=bar&amp;kitties=yay";
testAnchor.id = 'testAnchor';
document.body.appendChild(testAnchor);
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);   - running this in a js console should show that both ampersands in the URL get encoded. Again, sorry for the lack of a proper js fiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give a browser invalid HTML, then it will try to fix it up. If you then serialise the DOM to HTML, it will give you the fixed HTML. There is no way to avoid this.

OTOH, most x-url-form-encoded data parsers will follow [the recommendation to treat semi-colons as ampersands](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2) so `?foo=1&amp;bar=2` will be treated the same as `foo=1&amp=&bar=2` so you don't need to worry too much about copy/pasting. This also means you could just write `foo=1;bar=2` in the first place and not worry about having to encode ampersands for HTML.

Comment: I don't have any control of which URLs are input, so I can't do that (much as I would like to at this point!) -  I was worried you might say that its just correcting the HTML, but then you can print out the original input in chrome's js console using console.xmldir (node), so I figured it might be possible to get it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this with the DOM in JS, you could do something like this:

```
var e = document.createElement('span');
e.innerHTML = 'url here';
return e.innerText; // This is your URL
```

Comment: I think I mentioned (a bit vaguely, sorry - will update) that I need the HTML tag part as well, which innerText strips, so this doesn't help me. Thanks though!